# Resetting initializer/ObjectController data when testing Ember

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js

Ember 1.3.0, Data: 1.0.0.beta.4

I'm running an initializer to setup a `currentUser` controller to hold an authenticated user.

```
Em.Application.initializer({
    name: 'currentUser',
    initialize: function(container, App) {
      var ObjectController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
        #...init code, sets content to current user
      });
      container.register('currentUser:main', ObjectController);
      container.typeInjection('controller', 'currentUser', 'currentUser:main');
      container.typeInjection('route', 'currentUser', 'currentUser:main');
    },
 });
```

When testing, I'd like to be able to unregister this value or destroy the controller or somehow reset this, so I can test cases where the current user is logged out.

```
afterEach( function () {
  Ember.run(function() {
    var objectController = App.__container__.lookup("currentUser:main");
    if (typeof objectController === "object") {
      //Neither of these seem to work
      objectController.set('content', null);
      // OR this 
      objectController.destroy();
    }

    Rise.reset();
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. If I log the objectController inside the run loop I can see that I've either set the content to `null` or the `isDestroying` flag is set to true, but when I try to retrieve the content after this run loop, it returns the user or a promise containing the user.

Is there some way to really destroy this object?

Comment: Can you share the code for setting the user initially? Can you share the code for logging `objectController`'s `content`? It's unclear when you log it.